# Print regex match Perl

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, loops

Hello I am in the process of making a program that matches a given set of keywords to a file.

I want to output the matched data to a text file and include the regex keyword that triggered the match.

Below is my code related to my issue:

```
my $counter = 0;
foreach($words) 
{
    while($line = <FILE>)
    {
        if($line =~ /$words/)
        {
            print "@array[$counter] $line\n";
            print OUTPUT $line;
        }
    }
    $counter ++;
}
```

This does not produce the expected outcome. It works perfectly for the first element in the array but for the rest it just simply prints the first one again. I believe the counter is not being incremented.

Is there a better / easier way to get the current element being used in the loop? or even get the current regex match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you should do:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.016;

my $fname = 'data.txt';

my @patterns = (
    'do.',
    '.at',
    '.ir.',
);

open my $INFILE, '<', $fname
    or die "Couldn't read from $fname: $!";

while (my $line = <$INFILE>) {
    for my $pattern (@patterns) {
        if ($line =~ /($pattern)/) {
            print "$pattern --> $1";
        }
    }
}

close $INFILE:
```

1. Putting parentheses around parts of the regex causes perl to set the match variables $1, $2, $3, etc., which contain the match for each parenthesized group.
2. $line will have a newline at the end of the line, so if you write `print "$line\n"`, you will add another newline, so your output file will have blank lines between every line you print.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `<FILE>` exhausts the file for the first word. For the next word, `<FILE>` tries to read at the end of the file, which means the whole loop is skipped.

You can iterate over the words *inside* the loop over the file, or you can [seek](http://p3rl.org/seek)
back to the beginning of the file at the end of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would it be easier to just get the regex match? i.e. show what element in $words matched the $line? Nevermind I found a simple solution $& gets the current match, $` previous, and $' the next. Thanks anyway!